# How to remove prefix from file names that have x digit numeric prefix

Tags: bash, if-statement

With the help of the community I put the following script together that adds x digit random prefix to all files. The problem is that sometimes I need to add a new file and thats when my script get in trouble

```
#!/bin/bash

# validate input
[ -n "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s /path/to/files\n" "${0//\//}"
    exit 1
}

# validate directory
[ -d "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: directory not found: '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

path="$1"

## removing prefix
count=$(ls $path | cut -c1-10 | uniq | wc -l)
echo $count
echo $path
if [ $count = "1" ]
then
cd $path
for i in *; do mv "$i" `echo $i|cut -c11-`; done
echo "PREFIXES REMOVED"
else
echo "PREFIXES ARE NOT UNIQUE, SKIPPING"
fi

mask=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM; let "mask %= 10000000000";
len=$(echo ${#mask})
## Note: this assumes you are exporting mask earlier. If not, set mask here
## add validation for length 10
if [ $len -lt 10 ]; then
echo "mask is not 10" >&2
exit 1
fi
# move files
prefixcheck=$(ls $path | cut -c1-10 | uniq | wc -l)
if [ $prefixcheck != 1 ]
then
for i in "${path}"/*; do

    [ -f "$i" ] || continue  # if not file, skip

    dir="${i%/*}"            # path component
    ffname="${i##*/}"        # full filename component (with .ext)

    mv "$i" "${dir}/${mask}${ffname}"
    echo $mask " applied at " $(date) "in " $path >> /home/newprefix
done
else
echo "prefixes exist, skipping"
fi
```

Let's say I have 20 files with prefixes and i put a new file recording001.mp4 in the folder then my script will fail. How do I tell it to strip prefixes from all files where characters 1-10 in filename is numeric?

Comment: I guess your script fails because you firstly remove the prefix from every file name (first `for` loop)... including the name of new file, i.e, the new file `recording001.mp4` will be renamed as `01.mp4`

Comment: `cd "$path" && for i in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do mv "$i" "${i#??????????}"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the 10-digit prefix from the file names:

```
cd "$path" &&
for i in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
do
     mv "$i" "${i#??????????}"
done
```

Comment: `${i#?}` means the value of variable `i` with the first character removed. For instance, if `i=example` `${i#?}` would be `xample`, `${i#??}` would be `ample`, and so on... In this [web page about bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) read the explanation about `${parameter#word}`.